# Remove multiple Similar Words from String - Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

`description = "100 Kilogram/Kilograms"`
I need result "100 Kilogram"
Above is just an example, I will not know what will be similar in the description, Like it can be `description ="200 mt / mts" or description = "12.00 kilogram // kilograms" or description = "200 square meter / square meter"`
I'm looking for help that may facilitate to remove almost same words from a string.
Note: I will not know what exactly almost same there, or may not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches)

Here is an example:

```
import re
import difflib

description = "200 mt / mts"


def remove_same(string):
    striped = re.findall(r"[\w+.']+", string)
    for i in striped:
        same = difflib.get_close_matches(i, striped)
        if len(same) > 1:
            striped.remove(same[1])
    return " ".join(striped)


print(remove_same(description))
```

The output will be:

```
200 mts
```

Comment: Test it on this one
description = "200 Kilogram"
Although it is not similar, but it is remove the word Kilogram, Why ?

Comment: I have Used Your same Method, Just  initialized value of Description as "200 Kilogram" and it return me 200 only, it should return me 200 Kilogram because there is no same Words in description.

Comment: Just Do this ``` description = "200 kilogram"```  Output will be 200 but it should return  me 200 kilogram

Comment: Just last one,
set Description as "22.5 metric ton" it is returning 22 5 metric ton but it should return 22.5 metric ton, Can you please correct the code again ?

Comment: Edited. Check now